# Qt5 reference documentation: qch files

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5

I want to view Qt reference documentation inside QtAssistant, but the installation of Qt5 did not come with .qch documentation files for Qt libraries.

I have tried to find them on the http://qt-project.org but could not find them anywhere. 
How do I get the Qt5 documentation files ?

I am using Ubuntu 12.10, I have installed the new qt-library sdk from the qt-project website.

Comment: Telling what OS you have might be relevant. As a solution, you could get source package and build the docs from that...

Comment: I also faced same problem, then I installed qt5 libraries(5.0.1) and now it works

Answer (score 9):

Open `Assistant` (`5.0.1/gcc/bin/assistant`) and then go to `Edit` -> `Preferences` menu.

There's a `Documentation` tab. If the list is empty, add the `.qch` files found in the `5.0.1/gcc/doc/` directory.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytlnU.png) is how it looks. This is Ubuntu 12.10 as well.
Qt 5.0.1 installed with the `qt-linux-opensource-5.0.1-x86-offline.run` package (388Mb).

Comment: I'm on macOS Catalina 10.15.6, and download `qt 5.12.0` from `download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.12/5.12.0` . However, there isn't `doc` folder under the `Qt5.12.0` directory

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the official Ubuntu-documentation for Qt5 is very incomplete. You don't have information about nearly any class.

If you want to use the QtCreator/QtAssistant build from Ubuntu you have to acquire the docs yourself. I did and uploaded these on my personal Mega-account. Here are the [docs](https://mega.co.nz/#F!IEQViZBD!IH66QnC6nus5tKn7Sh7Usw). I installed the Qt framework with the installer from qt-project.org, grabbed the documentation and inserted it into the software-center-version.

I don't use QtAssistant as a stand-alone program but integrated in QtCreator. To add the docs to QtCreator go to Tools>Options>Help>Documentation and click add. Then select all .qch files, click apply and enjoy. Maybe try the way as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

After all, you can just [download](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/qtbase5-doc) the necessary *.deb file from the store of the Ubuntu packages, and install it on your system. As they wrote [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/qtbase5-doc/filelist), this package will install the *.qch files in `/usr/share/qt5/doc`. The pitfall is that you will have to remember that you have done that, since your Ubuntu will not take any records for you.